# Mobile Navbar won't show when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When viewing at mobile screen resolution and you select the mobile nav icon bar, **nothing happens**. The desired effect is to have the same main navigation be used in mobile. I have ensured my data-targets (mobile_nav) match, and that markup looks good, but am new to Bootstrap.  Any help appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Loading Fonts Awesome CDN from boostrapcdn.com -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<!-- add padding from best practices for fixed topbar navs -->
<header> 
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile_nav" >
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile_nav">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
</header>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is because you're not including jquery. include this before bootstrap js <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>. try this http://jsfiddle.net/xtvu23v1/1/

Comment: Maybe later than 1.2.1 for jQuery ... if you're starting a new application, don't you think 2+ is better? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @psalmody If you use jQuery 2 then you cannot target IE8.

Comment: Yup, just needed to add JQuery.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @DavidG Right - all depends on your target audience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap requires jQuery to work, you should include it before the Bootstrap JS in your HTML:

```
<!-- JQuery -->    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```